# Javascript + HTML: How can I efficiently display a large list of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, google-chrome-extension

Some context:
I'm making a chrome extension that will make use of a large list (potentially thousands) of image urls. The list will have urls for many image types.

I want to give users the ability to browse these images by seeing the actual image, and not just seeing the url. Right now I just iterate through the list, and for each url, I attach an  element to a scrollable element. This results in a a scrollable list of images. Some are gifs, some png, some jpeg etc. I'm worried that if the list gets very large, there will be a lot of lag and the process will take up a lot of bandwidth.

Is there a good way to do something like this efficiently (ie. reduce lag and loading times)?

Ideally I would have a thumbnail for each url.

Comment: you want to display thousends of images in one list and the images are at the original size?

Comment: The images would be at a fixed size. I kind of want to display them as thumbnails, but that would require each image to be converted or something I thought.

Comment: if you really want that amount of images in one site you need to create really small thumbs... like 64x64 or even smaller... i think an old pc would crash anyway if it has less than 1gb of ram.and as it's a google chrome extension use the new image format webp the size of a webp is average 30-40% smaller than any other image.and to reduce the requests you can create one big images or groups containing the thumbnails.and map that image with css

Comment: but yeah a better approach would be to use ajax and show a specific number of image per site... load a json file which contains all the links to the thumbs and images with description and whatever you need. an show maybe 20-50 or whatever images per site..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the thousands of images are not going to be all displayed at once in a single view but as you described, in a long list. The approach I would take would be to buffer the images and display them on scroll. This would require you to calculate how many images you can store in a row and have at least two or three rows buffered ahead and behind of the current scroll position. The only downside to this approach is that it could be tricky to get a smooth scrolling solution it the thumbnail rows are large.

Comment: The rows would only have two or three thumbnails. What do you mean by buffer? Is there a way to load the image without attaching an <img> element to the page?

Comment: @Lebowski156 ...sometimes you eat the bear, and sometimes, well, he eats you.

Comment: @Chris I've run into some issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692857/jquery-lazy-dynamic-content